# Error when trying to update a select case statement that contains an aggregate function (count)

Tags: sql, oracle

Purpose:
I want to verify that text within a single column fall into a specific category based on text of column and count of text per item_number listed (item_numbers are expected to be listed more than once with 4 rows(count) with 'textA' and 2 rows(count) with 'textB').

However, if the item_number does not meet the specific category then I would like a message returned indicating the discrepancy.

Current results:
I am receiving this error message: SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Script:

```
UPDATE TableA
 SET TableA.Column1 = T.Count
 from TableA JOIN (
   select TableA.item_1,TableA.object_2,
     case
     when count(object_2) !=4 and dobject_2 = 'textA'
     then 'ERROR_A'
     WHEN COUNT(object_2) !=2 AND object_2 = 'textB'
     ELSE 'ERROR_B'
     END AS Count
  from TableA 
  JOIN ac on (TableA.item_1 = ac.item_1 and TableA.object_2 = ac.object_2)
  where ac.object_3 in ('textC','textD',null)
  group by TableA.item_1,TableA.object_2
  )T on TableA.item_1 = t.item_1 and TableA.object_2 = t.object_2;
```

Comment: Oracle does not support `join` in the `update` statement.  Also, I am removing the "mysql" tag because the error message is from Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Your query has numerous problems, but I think this may be what you are looking for or close to it:

```
update tablea a
    set column1 = (select (case when count(object_2) <> 4 and object_2 = 'textA'
                                then 'ERROR_A'
                                when COUNT(object_2) <> 2 and object_2 = 'textB'
                                then 'ERROR_B'
                           end)
                   from ac
                   where TableA.item_1 = ac.item_1 and TableA.object_2 = ac.object_2 and
                         (ac.object_3 in ('textC', 'textD') or ac.object_3 is null)
                   group by object_2
                  );
```

Apart from the obvious syntax issues (because Oracle does not support `join` in `update`), there is also:

- The `case` statement was missing a `then` clause (I changed the `else` to `then`).
- The `NULL` in the `in` list is nonsensical; it does nothing so I added a separate check.
- SQL uses `<>` for "not equals", although many databases do support `!=`.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  However, the script did not work.  To clarify "AC" is not a table it is an alias.  TableA is the only table being used.  Please advise.

Comment: @tcc . . . `join ac`.  In your original query, `ac` is a table or view.

Comment: @Gordon...I got the join statement from an example on Stack.  It did not work properly.  Actually I am only using 1 table to derive the results.  The ac can be removed it is not an actual table.

Comment: UPDATE TableA
 SET TableA.Column1 = T.Count
 from TableA JOIN (
   select TableA.item_1,TableA.object_2,
     case
     when count(object_2) !=4 and dobject_2 = 'textA'
     then 'ERROR_A'
     WHEN COUNT(object_2) !=2 AND object_2 = 'textB'
     ELSE 'ERROR_B'
     END AS Count
  from TableA 
  JOIN TableA on (TableA.item_1 = TableA.item_1 and TableA.object_2 = TableA.object_2)
  where TableA.object_3 in ('textC','textD',null)
  group by TableA.item_1,TableA.object_2
  )T on TableA.item_1 = t.item_1 and TableA.object_2 = t.object_2;